# How to add event ability to object instance in Node?

Tags: node.js, events

It's ok to add event ability to a constructor:

```
function Stream() {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}
util.inherits(Stream, events.EventEmitter);
```

But how to add event ability to an **object instance**? The following code doesn't work:

```
var foo = {x: 1, y: 2};
util.inherits(foo, event.EventEmitter);
events.EventEmitter.call(foo);
```

After running the above code, `foo.on` still be `undefined`.
Is there a way to inherit or mix-in EventEmitter's content?

Comment: For those like me don't understand this is because you can't change prototype after creation, you need a constructor to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the npm module `node.extend`.
It is a port of jQuery's `$.extend` and with it, you can do this:

```
var extend = require('node.extend'),
    events = require('events');
extend(foo, events.EventEmitter.prototype);
```

or, if you don't want to use another module, you can use this:

```
function extend(target) {
    var sources = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return sources.forEach(function (source) {
        Object.keys(source).forEach(function (key) {
            target[key] = source[key];
        });
    }), target;
}
var events = require('events');
var foo = {x: 1, y: 2};

extend(foo, events.EventEmitter.prototype);
```