# how to call EventEmitter on an existing object

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, eventemitter

I would like to set up an existing object to be an EventEmitter, e.g.:

```
var emitter = {};
EventEmitter.call(emitter);
console.log(emitter.on);
```

However, emitter.on is undefined, instead of being a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add event ability to object instance in Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925115/how-to-add-event-ability-to-object-instance-in-node)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you got the notion that:

```
 EventEmitter.call(emitter);
```

would magically empower your emitter object with all EventEmitter functionality.  What that statement does is call the EventEmitter constructor and pass it your object as the `this` argument.  That will cause the constructor to execute and probably set some data on your `emitter` object, but it does not attach the `EventEmitter` prototype to your object in any way, thus any methods on the `EventEmitter` prototype are not bound to your object and thus why `.on()` is `undefined`.

---

There are multiple ways to take on the functionality of an existing object depending upon what you're can control and are trying accomplish.

If you control the definition of the object that you want to become an `EventEmitter`, then you will just want to inherit from an EventEmitter object and then your object will just "be" an `EventEmitter` and have all of its methods and data.

Inherit with ES6 class syntax:

```
// myobj.js
const EventEmitter = require('events');

// inherit directly from EventEmitter
class MyObj extends EventEmitter {
  constructor () {
    super() 
  }
  // your other custom methods here
}

module.exports = MyObj;
```

Then, you would use that like this:

```
const MyObj = require("myobj.js");
let obj = new MyObj();
obj.on("hello", data => {
    console.log("got hello message");
});

obj.emit("hello", "to you");
```

---

If you don't control the definition or construction of the object that you want to give EventEmitter logic to, then you need to decide if you want to "be a" or "have a" EventEmitter.

In the "be a" path (where you want your object to "be a" `EventEmitter` in addition to its own function, you mix in the logic of an EventEmitter object and add all the methods and data to your own object after your own object has been created.  This is not foolproof because some types of object may rely on private data which you cannot appropriate mix-in.  But, it does work for many objects.

For `EventEmitter`, there is a specific module that has been built to allow you to "mixin" and `EventEmitter`.  It's called [component-emitter on NPM](https://github.com/component/emitter) and is very easy to use.  socket.io uses it [right here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L75) so that it's socket object can be an `EventEmitter`.

```
var Emitter = require('component-emitter');

/**
 * Mix in `Emitter`.
 */

Emitter(Socket.prototype);
```

---

For the "has a" path, you simply create an `EventEmitter` object and put it in your own object's instance data and then refer to that particular object for your `EventEmitter` functionality.  You can either manually get that object and use it or you can have some methods that just automatically use it.  This is simpler and more foolproof to implement, but not as convenient to use in some cases (it all really depends on the details of what you're trying to do).

```
class MyObj {
  constructor () {
    super() 
    this.myEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  }
  // your other custom methods here
  broadcast(msg, data) {
      // use the internal eventEmitter object we have in our instance data
      this.myEmitter.emit(msg, data);
  }
}

module.exports = MyObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use [ES6 Class syntax via the `class` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) and use  the [`extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) keyword to create a Subclass of `EventEmitter`. Below is a trivial example of how to create your own `EventEmitter` via [Prototypal Inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

```
// MyEmitter.js
const EventEmitter = require('events')

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  constructor () {
    super() 
    this.emit('created', 'New Instance of MyEmitter Created')
  }
}

module.exports = MyEmitter
```

---

```
// index.js
const MyEmitter = require('./MyEmitter')

// Create a new instance of MyEmitter
const emitter = new MyEmitter()

// Attach an Event Listener for the 'created' event
// Print whatever the message is to stdout
emitter.on('created', message => console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this in two ways, is either you extend the `EventEmitter` class or you set the prototype of `emitter` to the prototype of `EventEmitter`;

```
// using es6 class 

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
    } 
}

const emitter = new MyEmitter();

emitter.on("greet", greet => console.log(greet));

emitter.emit("greet", "hello");

// if you want to use this on a different file you have to export the emitter object



// the second alternative if you don't want to use a class

const emitter = {};

Object.setPrototypeOf(emitter, events.prototype); 

// or

Object.setPrototypeOf(emitter, events.EventEmitter.prototype);

emitter.on("greet", greet => console.log(greet));

emitter.emit("greet", "hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can still use `EventEmitter.call(emitter);`

here's the trick:

```
const MyFunctionEmitter = function() { 
    EventEmitter.call(this, {objectMode: true});
     
    this.on('myevent', function(s) { 
      console.log(s)
    })

  }

MyFunctionEmitter.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype, {
    constructor: { value: MyFunctionEmitter }
}); 

//inherit and apply native event emitter to our myFunction object
util.inherits(MyFunctionEmitter, EventEmitter);  
  
  var myEmitter = new MyFunctionEmitter() 
  myEmitter.emit('myevent', 'my event message')
```